# Resize UITableViewCell to UILabel's height dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, math

I want to resize cell's height according to the label's height and label's height according to text. Or is there any way I can resize the cell's height according to the text entered in `UITextView`?

Comment: Are you saying you want to resize a UITableViewCell containing a UITextView as more text is entered into the text view?

Comment: no sir i have a custom cell with label on the cell.and text is coming from the database.
how do i increase cell row height and label no of lines or label height so that long text can be fitted into cell's label

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable UITableCellView height with subview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128012/variable-uitablecellview-height-with-subview)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**THIS METHOD IS DEPRECATED SINCE iOS 7.0.**

There is a `UITableView` delegate method called `heightForRowAtIndexPath` that is called before you create a cell or a table.

You could use the `NSIndexPath` passed to it to get the text at a specific row and use the `sizeWithFont` method from `UIStringDrawing.h` to compute a `CGSize` for that row.

For example:

```
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font
                   constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

And finally you would return `size.height`.

Comment: This method has been deprecated in iOS7.

Answer (score 6):

--For iOS7--

Basing this off of Josh Vera's answer … place this in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

I have my table data stored in an NSArray *tableData.

```
// set the desired width of the textbox that will be holding the adjusted text, (for clarity only, set as property or ivar)
CGFloat widthOfMyTexbox = 250.0;

-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Get a reference to your string to base the cell size on.
    NSString *cellText = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //set the desired size of your textbox
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(widthOfMyTextBox, MAXFLOAT);
    //set your text attribute dictionary
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    //get the size of the text box
    CGRect textsize = [cellText boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];
    //calculate your size
    float textHeight = textsize.size.height +20;
    //I have mine set for a minimum size
    textHeight = (textHeight < 50.0) ? 50.0 : textHeight;

    return textHeight;
}
```

I haven't tested it for iOS<7, but I believe it should work for that as well.

Comment: can you explain what widthOfMyTextBox refers to?

Comment: Scratcha see updated answer. It's the width that you want your textbox to be.