# How to prevent a UITableViewCell's textLabel from truncating its text on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uilabel

I am using a `UITableView` on an iPad and for some reason the `UITableViewCell.textLabel`'s text is getting truncated even though there's plenty of space to display the text. I tried all of the following, none of which fixed it:

1. Set a flexible width autosizing mask on the cell
2. Calling `[cell sizeToFit]` after setting the text
3. Calling `[cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0]` and `[cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]`

I haven't yet tried subclassing UITableViewCell and setting the frame explicitly in the layoutSubviews method. Trying to avoid that as I feel like there should be a better solution. I also don't want to resize the text--there is plenty of space to fit the text at the full font size.

[image]

Comment: How are you displaying those numbers on the right side by the ">" ? Have you aded a custom accessory view?

Comment: I am adding a UILabel as a subview to the cell. However, I have tried commenting out the UILabel and it still doesn't work.

Comment: So, if you comment that out, the cell is just a standard "Basic" cell with a disclosure indicator, nothing else?

Comment: Correct: 
`cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];`

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem. You should try adding a background color to your label to make sure what its size is. When I do this, it shows the label going all the way up to the disclosure indicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer had nothing to do with UITableViewCell in the end. There was a section of the code truncating the text to display in the table view cell! Thanks everyone for the help up to this point.

Answer (score 7):

u set set textLabel number of line 0

```
     cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;
     cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap; or NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

hope it help you

Comment: I tried that to no avail. I updated my question with this info. FYI UILineBreakModeWordWrap is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Set the "setNumberOfLines" property of the label to wrap the text to required number of lines. 
If you don't want the "..." at the end of the text if it is too long then use

cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;  or NSLineBreakByWordWrapping for ios 6 or more

Try to set height and width of textlable and tableviewcell dynamicaly refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827126/change-the-uitableviewcell-height-according-to-amount-of-text)

Comment: I tried that to no avail. I updated my question with this info. FYI UILineBreakModeWordWrap is deprecated.

Comment: use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping for ios 6 or more

Comment: Why would setting the height make any difference? There should be plenty of room to display the text in the default height.

Comment: have look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129502/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-uitableviewcell-without-a-custom-cell

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. this happened to me in ios 6 and this also happened to me with you customized cells. I used multiline and NSLineBreakByWordWrapping.

I've solved changing all labels to use NSLineBreakByCharWrapping