# Expanding UITableViewcell Dynamically when enter text on UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITextView` in all the cells of a `UITableview`.  The text view's height is increasing dynamically. As the text view size increases, I would like to increase that cell's height.
I am writing as

```
    -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView1 shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
    {

        NSLog(@"textTag%d",textView1.tag);

        NSString *stringToSave = [textView1.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
        NSLog(@"Save me: %@", stringToSave);

     CGFrame*frame =textView1.frame;
        frame.size.height = textView1.contentSize.height;
        textView1.frame = frame;
```

//HERE I NEED TO INCREASE THE HIGHT FOR THE PARTICULAR CELL.

```
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textView1 resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return  YES;
}
```

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                                heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 1):

insert these lines:

```
//class variable, type float
newHeight = textView1.contentSize.height;
//class variable, type int
cellIndex = /*set index of your cell for which you want extended height*/
[yourTable reloadData];
```

below these lines:

```
CGFrame*frame =textView1.frame;
        frame.size.height = textView1.contentSize.height;
        textView1.frame = frame;
```

And in heightForRowAtIndexPath method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == cellIndex)
    {
        return newHeight;
    }
    return regularHeigh;
}
```

Comment: when i am writing these method it is showing error

Comment: what error? please post.

Comment: is it correct    if ( [self tableView:idationFlowTbl heightForRowAtIndexPath:0]) {
        return 100;
        [idationFlowTbl beginUpdates];
            [idationFlowTbl endUpdates];
    }

Comment: This is a callback method, you should not call it directly. But even if you do, it won't do anything.

Comment: Ok how can i call that method

Comment: now check edited answer..

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom growing TextView called [HPGrowingTextView](https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView) to your cell . 
Then change the height of the cell as shown in the question

[Change the UITableViewCell Height According to Amount of Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827126/change-the-uitableviewcell-height-according-to-amount-of-text)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could map the heights of the cells in a `NSMutableArray`. 
The array will contain the standard heights that you have.

You can tag the `UITextView` with the `indexPath.row` so you know which item to load from the array.

And you can override the value from the array according with the textview's height.

Then in your

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 return [[mycellsizearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]floatValue];
}
```

Now you should have the heights according with your needs.