# Calculate cell height based on cell's text in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

There are many solutions out there that use "sizeWithFont" or something similar, which happens to be deprecated as of iOS 7.

Here is some code I have pieced together so far. The height changes, but not at all accurately:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = "The Cell's Text!";
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[cell.textLabel sizeToFit];

return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBounds.size;

NSAttributedString *aString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:"The Cell's Text!"];
UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[calculationView setAttributedText:aString];
CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(screenSize.width, FLT_MAX)];
return size.height;
}
```

For another example, here's a *similar* answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9828777/693121 though as I said before, this utilizes deprecated code.

Answer (score 14):

You should use the method that's mentioned in the docs to replace the old one -- boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:. Here's an example that I think should work (it works with multi-line labels anyway).

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSStringDrawingContext *ctx = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
    NSAttributedString *aString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"The Cell's Text!"];
    UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [calculationView setAttributedText:aString];
    CGRect textRect = [calculationView.text boundingRectWithSize:self.view.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:calculationView.font} context:ctx];
        return textRect.size.height;
  }
```

This assumes that you want the text view to be the size of self.view. If not, you should use initWithFrame for your text view, and pass calculationView.frame.size for the boundingRectWithSize: parameter.

Comment: For some reason this always returns a height of 13.8? Regardless of the amount of text in "aString" variable.

Comment: @Demasterpl, sorry, I used the wrong options parameter in my answer, it should be NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: That seems to be returning a respectable value, although sometimes even though the height is a large number, it still appears to maintain default height. Also, it didn't seem to make a difference if I removed cell properties (like sizeToFit & setLineBreakMode). :(

Comment: @Demasterpl,, what maintains the default height? The cell, or the text view?

Comment: Sorry to take to long to reply, but it all appears to be random. I can't nail down what's consistent.

Comment: can you please answer the question on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155143/nscfstring-boundingrectwithsizeoptionsattributescontext-unrecognized-s

Comment: I get a 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error on the boundingRecWithSize call.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts, what is the full error message, and what version of iOS are you building for?

Comment: I have NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin in there and I'm still getting the 13.8  that @Demasterpl was getting.

Answer (score 8):

This here is the easiest version, iOS 7 does all the heavy lifting (only for autolayout-based uitableviewcells):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"Cell"];

   [self configureCell:cell];

   // edit: Need to call [cell layoutIfNeeded]; otherwise the layout changes wont be applied to the   cell

   [cell layoutIfNeeded];


   return [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
}
```

systemLayoutSizeFittingSize re-evaluates the autolayout constraints and returns the perfect height for your cell. Easy, right?

Comment: what does the method [self configureCell:cell]; ?

Comment: basic setup of the cell dependent of the data object (e.g., setting labels). with it i "fill" the cell with content, thus autolayout can determine the required height automatically

Answer (score 2):

I got it from my colleague (ANIRUDH) and working fine, may be helpful:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//Calculating height on base of length of text
    UIFont *font =  [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:YOURSTRING //[NSString string withformat:@"\n Yourstring"] \n for: number of lines require for static label in cell
     attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName: font
     }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;

    //  NSString *height = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", ceilf(size.height)+22];
    return (ceilf(size.height)+22)*0.6; //change 0.6 to 0.9 according to the difference in required and extra calculted height, it works for me every time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *yourText = [[resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"review_text"];
    CGSize lblwidth = CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize requiredSize = [yourText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CALIBRI" size:17] constrainedToSize:lblwidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    int calculatedHeight = requiredSize.height+50;
    return (float)calculatedHeight;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the size of your string you should use `- (CGSize)sizeWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attars`.

So for your example you would calculate the height of the text label as such:

```
CGSize *cellSize = [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[cell.textLabel.font]}];
```

or

```
CGSize *rowSize = [aString sizeWithAttributes:nil];
```

Comment: This will not work. From Apple's docs: "Returns the size of the string if it were to be rendered with the specified font on a single line." That's not useful if you're trying to change cell height based on a multi-line label.