# -[__NSCFString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios7, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

```
@interface PromotionsListViewController : UITableViewController 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PromotionCell";
PromotionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[PromotionCell alloc] init];
}

// Configure the cell...
Promotion *promotion = [self.promotionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:promotion.imageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
cell.lblTitle.text = promotion.promotionTitle;

return cell;
}
@interface PromotionCell : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imgView;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *lblTitle;

@end
- (void)layoutSubviews {

if (self.lblTitle.text) {

    CGSize maxsize = CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    CGRect calculateRect = [_lblTitle.text boundingRectWithSize:maxsize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:_lblTitle.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle.copy} context:nil];

    _lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(_lblTitle.frame.origin.x, 300 - calculateRect.size.height - 5, _lblTitle.frame.size.width, calculateRect.size.height);

} else {
    _lblTitle.frame = CGRectZero;
}
}
- (UILabel *)lblTitle {

if (!_lblTitle) {

    _lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 250, 300, 50)];
    _lblTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22.0f];
    _lblTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
    _lblTitle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [self.contentView addSubview:_lblTitle];
}
return _lblTitle;
}
```

Can anybody plz tell me what am I doing wrong? I hope my Question is clear..

Comment: I think the error message is quite clear... You are calling boundingRectWithSize on an object that doesn't recognise the method. Where is the error located on? Can you just remove your code that doesn't have anything to do with the error message?

Comment: Are you running this code on iOS 7 simulator/device or previous? Running on previous iOS version will throw this error as `boundingRectWithSize:` method is introduced in iOS 7.

Comment: @Geek This is not accurate. `boundingRectWithSize:` was introduced in iOS 6. Source: [Apple Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/boundingRectWithSize:options:context:)

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem too. Turns out there are two similar methods for `boundingRectWithSize:`. One for `NSString` and one for `NSAttributedString`.

The following for NSAttributedString is available for iOS 6 and above:

`- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context`

The other NSString method (which you're currently using) is only available on iOS 7:

`- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context`

So just call the `boundingRectWithSize:` method without an extra `Attributes:` field on your  Attributed String and it'll work fine on iOS 6.

Comment: @Jack Dewhurst , I removed `Attributes:`, but error: `No visible @interface for NSString declares the selector boundingRectWithSize:options:context:`

Comment: Solved by convert NSString to NSAttributedString