# Dynamic UITableView Cell Heights Programmatically IOS7 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've been facing the problem since i decided to support IOS7, i was using `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` which is working well only with IOS8. and since `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`doesn't work with IOS7 so i have to handle it manually. but there is no such resource to help in swift about this issue.

i am using custom cell called "Card Cell" :

```
class CardCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var text1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sharefb: UIButton!

}
```

so if there is anyway to handle it in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` manually using swift ?

Comment: Can I see your code via github? I can take a look.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin , which code you want to see ? the heightForRowAtIndexPath function or what exactly ?

Comment: your storyboard. I want to see how you declare the constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 7 you need to implement `UITableViewDelegate` protocol method and return your cell height.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0;
}
```

Comment: i tried to do it, but the "Text Label" is not dynamic which allow 3 lines and crop the rest and this is not acceptable , so it didn't work as UITableViewAutomaticDimension in IOS8 !

Comment: You need to return exact height in pixes it's not automatic. If you want to calculate cell height based on cell content than you need refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203193/calculate-cell-height-based-on-cells-text-in-ios-7

Comment: may i ask you to rewrite the code from objective-c to swift ? i really can't understand objective-c !

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

before these two lines

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
tableView.cellHeight = UITableViewCellAutomaticDimension
```