# Adjust UILabel height to text

Tags: ios, swift, height, uilabel, frame

I have some labels which I want to adjust their height to the text, this is the code I wrote for this now

```
func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
```

**EDIT:**

The issue was not in this piece of code, so my fix is in the question itself. It might still be useful for others!

Comment: Take a look at NSString UIKit additions, there are methods there to calculate the size as you need without creating a UILabel.

Comment: @VladimirGritsenko the 'sizeWithFont' methods are unavailable in Swift :(

Comment: I admit I'm not an expert on Swift, but I believe you can add your own bridging methods. Would still be worth it over creating UILabel to calculate size.

Comment: @TheBurgerShot `sizeWithFont` may not be available for Swift `String` but it is available on `NSString` You should still be able to call it on that.

Comment: In the end, the error was something different and had nothing to do with this method. Though this might still be helpful for others.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

I've just put this in a playground and it works for me.

**Updated for Swift 4.0**

```
import UIKit

 func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}

let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20.0)

var height = heightForView("This is just a load of text", font: font, width: 100.0)
```

**Swift 3:**

```
func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()

    return label.frame.height
}
```

[image]

Comment: this works fine for mee too in playground, the error does not seem to occur at this specific place, when i remove the usages of this method it is gonna whine about some println's or just a line with only comments (then it says EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 as well)

Comment: It works in a playground, but no sizing occurs as desired inside of a view controller in XCode 6.1

Comment: I am a little hesitant to create a new `UILabel` per sizing; if this method is used inside `layoutSubviews` with the tendency to be invoked multiple times per complete layout, the extra object creation may introduce noticeable delays, especially during scrolling.

Comment: let textRect = textString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(320, 2000), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: textAttributes, context: nil)

Comment: I am unable to call this function in my view controller...Can you suggest me what could be the possible reason?

Comment: this will not working as I expected I want the label size equal to my view and height be dynamic depend on text and label be at the bottom of the view how can I do that ?

Answer (score 69):

**If you are using AutoLayout**, you can adjust `UILabel` height by config UI only.

**For iOS8 or above**

- Set constraint leading/trailing for your `UILabel`
- And change the lines of `UILabel` from 1 to 0

[image]

**For iOS7**

- *First*, you need to add contains height for `UILabel`
- *Then*, modify the Relation from `Equal` to `Greater than or Equal`

[image]

- *Finally*, change the lines of `UILabel` from 1 to 0

[image]

Your `UILabel` will automatically increase height depending on the text

Comment: And if the label is inside a cell. When and how would you increase the cell height accordingly?

Comment: @oyalhi, if your label is inside a tableview cell, please see my other post http://stackoverflow.com/a/36277840/5381331

Comment: This worked perfectly for me!   Setup the constraints, and it will work properly!

Comment: not working for me...the word "Label" in a UILabel makes height=20.  It remains 20 after this setting.

Comment: No idea what "add contains height for UILabel" means, and there is no "Height Constraint" section in UIBuilder  with First Item (pictured)??

Answer (score 11):

I have the strong working solution.

in layoutSubviews:

```swift
title.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 0)
title.sizeToFit()
title.frame.size = title.bounds.size
```

in text setter:

```
title.text = newValue
setNeedsLayout()
```

**UPD.**
of course with this UILabel settings:

```
title.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
title.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: proved.. thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

Only **3 steps**

**Step 1)**

```
//To calculate height for label based on text size and width
func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
```

**Step 2)**

```
//Call this function
let height = heightForView(text: "This is your text", font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17), width: 300)
print(height)//Output : 41.0
```

**Step 3)**

```
//This is your label
let proNameLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 300, height: height))
proNameLbl.text = "This is your text"
proNameLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
proNameLbl.numberOfLines = 0
proNameLbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
infoView.addSubview(proNameLbl)
```

Answer (score 10):

I create this extension if you want

```
extension UILabel {
    func setSizeFont (sizeFont: CGFloat) {
        self.font =  UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: sizeFont)!
        self.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

based on Anorak's answer, I also agree with  Zorayr's concern, so I added a couple of lines to remove the UILabel and return only the CGFloat, I don't know if it helps since the original code doesn't add the UIabel, but it doesn't throw error, so I'm using the code below:

```
func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{

    var currHeight:CGFloat!

    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()

    currHeight = label.frame.height
    label.removeFromSuperview()

    return currHeight
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just by setting:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

The label automatically adjusts its height based upon the amount of text entered.

Comment: This does not make the UILabel to adjust it's height.

Answer (score 6):

The solution suggested by Anorak as a computed property in an extension for UILabel:

```
extension UILabel
{
var optimalHeight : CGFloat
    {
        get
        {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, CGFloat.max))
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode
            label.font = self.font
            label.text = self.text

            label.sizeToFit()

            return label.frame.height
         }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
self.brandModelLabel.frame.size.height = self.brandModelLabel.optimalHeight
```

Comment: Cannot assign to property: 'height' is a get-only property.

Answer (score 4):

Following on @Anorak answer, i added this extension to String and sent an inset as a parameter, because a lot of times you will need a padding to your text.
Anyway, maybe some you will find this usefull.

```
extension String {

    func heightForWithFont(font: UIFont, width: CGFloat, insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> CGFloat {

        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width + insets.left + insets.right, CGFloat.max))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = self

        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height + insets.top + insets.bottom
    }
}
```

Comment: label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping this line helped me thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to calculate the text height in Swift. You can then get the height from the rect and set the constraint height of the label or textView, etc.

```
let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 25)!
let text = "This is some really long text just to test how it works for calculating heights in swift of string sizes. What if I add a couple lines of text?"

let textString = text as NSString

let textAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]

let textRect = textString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(320, 2000), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: textAttributes, context: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

just call this method where you need dynamic Height for label

```
func getHeightforController(view: AnyObject) -> CGFloat {
    let tempView: UILabel = view as! UILabel
    var context: NSStringDrawingContext = NSStringDrawingContext()
    context.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8

    var width: CGFloat = tempView.frame.size.width

    width = ((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)/320)*width

    let size: CGSize = tempView.text!.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(width, 2000), options:NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: tempView.font], context: context).size as CGSize

    return size.height
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.0**

self.messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 70, y: 60, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 80, height: 30)

```
messageLabel.text = message

messageLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping //in versions below swift 3 (messageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping)    
messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0 //To write any number of lines within a label scope

messageLabel.textAlignment = .center

messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.white

messageLabel.font = messageLabel.font.withSize(12)

messageLabel.sizeToFit()
```

> Blockquote NSParagraphStyle.LineBreakMode, apply to entire paragraphs, not words within paragraphs.This property is in effect both during normal drawing and in cases where the font size must be reduced to fit the label’s text in its bounding box. This property is set to byTruncatingTail by default.

[This link describes the storyboard way of doing the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8KQQ.png)

Comment: Code-only answers are not considered good practice. Please consider adding some explanations on how your answer addresses the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.0**

Instead of calculating the text/label height, I just resize the label after inserting the (dynamic) text.

Assuming that myLabel is the UILabel in question:

```
let myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: *somewidth*, height: *placeholder, e.g. 20*))
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
myLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
...
```

And now comes the fun part:

```
var myLabelText: String = "" {
   didSet {
      myLabel.text = myLabelText
      myLabel.sizeToFit()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The **Swift 4.1** extension method to calculate label height:

```
extension UILabel {

    func heightForLabel(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = text

        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5, XCode 11 storyboard way. I think this works for iOS 9 and higher. You want for example "Description" label to get the dynamic height, follow the steps:

1) Select description label -> Go to Attributes Inspector (pencil icon), set:
Lines: 0
Line Break: Word Wrap

2) Select your UILabel from storyboard and go to Size Inspector (ruler icon), 
3) Go down to "Content Compression Resistance Priority to 1 for all other UIView (lables, buttons, imageview, etc) components that are interacting with your label.

For example, I have UIImageView, Title Label, and Description Label vertically in my view. I set Content Compression Resistance Priority to UIImageView and title label to 1 and for description label to 750. This will make a description label to take as much as needed height.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sizeThatFits` function.

For example:

`label.sizeThatFits(superView.frame.size).height`

Answer (score 0):

To make label dynamic in swift , don't give height constarint  and in storyboard make label number of lines  0 also give bottom constraint  and this is the best way i am handling dynamic label as per their content size .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dynamic text on the UILabel, and the height changes all the time (and nothing works), one alternative is putting the label inside a UIStackView

Comment: Why would you put a single label in a stack view? What issue does that solve that appropriate constraints on the label don't solve?