# Swift: UILabel how to show all text

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am very new to Swift and I don't know how to make my UILabel show all text.

Here is how my label looks like in my storyboard:[image]

As you see, part of the text is omitted. I can show all the text by dragging the UILabel to resize. However, during the runtime, if the text is set dynamically, how can I resize the label so that it can show more all of the text?

I tried `UILabel.sizeToFit()` but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do this by setting `numberOfLines` to `0`

**Example**

```
 myLabel.text = "whatever"
 myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
 myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

And you have so set frame according to it

Refer : [to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180443/adjust-uilabel-height-to-text-swift)

Answer (score 4):

> `YourUILabel.sizeToFit()` is right but that is not all of it..

You need to set the number of lines and the kind of line break before calling `.sizeToFit()`..

> `YourUILabel.numberOfLines` equal to `0` for unlimited number of
>   lines...
>
> `YourUILabel.lineBreakMode` equal to `NSLineBreakMode` dot(.)
>   `ByWordWrapping` for example..

Answer (score 2):

If you **are not resizing** the `UILabel` frame using autolayout you can change the Autoshrink option by selecting your label from the storyboard and adjust this option on the inspector pane.

[image].

Answer (score 1):

Why do it the old way.. Let's use **autolayout**. If you haven't used it yet. Lets begin - Steps :

1. Create a UIlabel and set it's width to any amount you want it on screen.
2. Select the label go to Editor menu -> Pin and one by one pin Leading Trailing and Top space to Superview (not the bottom one).
3. Since you have fixed width and you have dynamic height so also pin Width.
4. Go to Attribute inspector tab and set lines to 0 (means unlimited).
5. Go To size inspector and set Content Hugging priority(250/251) to low and Content Resistance priority to high (say - 750).

And you are done.!!*(not a single line of code)*

Answer (score 0):

You first have to calculate the Height of label according to the length of the Text you want to set and then accordingly increase the number of lines 
 as

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = "Your calculation number"
```

and then Set the Frame of the Label according to the Height calculated 
and

if you cannot calculate the height of the Label then i would say use the **TextView**  it will automatically add a scroll to the text and you can view all the text.

Comment: if you set number of lines to 0 it'll assume multiple lines. no calculation needed.