# How to give dynamic height to UILabel programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have taken UIlabel which are generated dynamically using for loop, each type diff text is assign in label, I want to give UILabel size dynamically depending on text.

Is there any easy solution in to do that in Swift?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Yes,I have use it in stroryBoard , But dont have use it programatically yet,

Answer (score 11):

```
let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height))
label.numberOfLines = 4
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20.0)
label.font = font
label.text = "Whatever you want the text enter here"
label.sizeToFit()
```

If you want to set numberOfLines according to the content of text,give your maximum lines.That is very important here.

Comment: what should I pass in "heigh"?

Comment: You can pass any value to "height" since sizeToFit() function will again adjust the height to fit content.

Answer (score 5):

get a label height depending on it's text, font, and width you assign to it:

```
func rectForText(text: String, font: UIFont, maxSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let attrString = NSAttributedString.init(string: text, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font])
        let rect = attrString.boundingRectWithSize(maxSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
        let size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)
        return size
    }

let labelSize = rectForText("your text here", font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(your font), maxSize: CGSizeMake(your label width,999))
let labelHeight = labelSize.height //here it is!
```

Comment: This worked great for me! I used the same code just updated for Swift 3

Comment: @May Phyu I just edited it with an update, should be here when it goes through review, if you still need it!

Answer (score 5):

```
    myLabel.text = "Your Label Text Here"

    myLabel.textAlignment = .Natural

    myLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    myLabel.sizeToFit()

    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(myLabel.frame.origin.x, myLabel.frame.origin.y, 280, myLabel.frame.height)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let label:UILabel = UILabel()
label.textColor=UIColor.black
label.font = UIFont(name: "Halvetica", size: 17)
label.numberOfLines = 1

label.text = item.name
label.sizeToFit()

label.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: imageView.frame.height+10, width: 50, height:label.frame.height)
```

Comment: i think its helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

Create Extension to calculate the height of label following method return height of the label

```
 import UIKit

func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
 let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
 label.numberOfLines = 0
 label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
 label.font = font
 label.text = text

 label.sizeToFit()
 return label.frame.height
}

let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20.0)
var height = heightForView("This is just a load of text", font: font, width: 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let label = UILabel()
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
label.text = "Hello,world.\n Just a test."
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17.0)
label.font = font
label.numberOfLines = 0;
let text = label.text! as NSString
let size = text.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:font])
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
```

You can use Auto Layout in code. [See Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html)

Answer (score 1):

The **Swift 4.1** extension method to calculate label height:

```
extension UILabel {

    func heightForLabel(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = text

        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height
    }

}
```

Refer: [Adjust UILabel height to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180443/adjust-uilabel-height-to-text/50609089#50609089)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString(string: "hello this is a string").boundingRect(
        with: CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude),
        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [.font: self],
        context: nil).size
```

Use this method to get determine the size for you string. Put maximum height and maximum width in `CGSize(widhth,height)` and it will return `CGSize` object containing height and width. Use it according with your scenario