# Unable to adjust height of a Label dynamically according to its text

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have mentioned my code below where I want to adjust my label height according to the text. In the picture below, black background is the label and this label is inserted into a UIScrollView. Label is aligned with the top left corner of the scroll view but when I run my app following is the display of view controller i.e. label has gone far below the top left corner of the scrollview. Please help me in this matter 
    [image]

```
func getLabelsHeightAccordingToTheTextContent() -> CGFloat
        {

        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, CGFloat.max))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = outletLabel.font
        label.text = outletLabel.text
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

        var fontName: String = outletLabel.font.fontName

        label.font = UIFont (name: fontName, size: outletLabel.font.pointSize)


        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height
    }
```

when i get the height of label, I set the height of scrollview

```
let height = getLabelsHeightAccordingToTheTextContent()
        let width = outletScrollView.frame.width
```

following are the properties of the label....................................
[image]

Comment: Are you using a scroll view so that people can scroll through the text?

Comment: see the link to do that..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180443/adjust-uilabel-height-to-text i hope this will help you..

Comment: line break mode should be word wrap

Comment: yes @olivierwilkinson i am using a scroll view so that people can scroll through the text. I have already seen the above link. It didn't help me in my case

Comment: In that case, while you could do it this way, it is much easier to use a UITextView. Scrolling is built in for that and you can set editing to false to stop people changing the text themselves.

Comment: so should i remove the scroll view which is under label?

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson so should i remove the scroll view which is under label?

Comment: Yeah, scrap the label and scroll view and add a UITextView and set its properties to be the same as you have for the label. Then in the storyboard set the TextView's editing property to false so people can't type in it. Maybe for now add the textView in the storyboard but don't delete the label and scroll view, just set their hidden property to true in viewDidLoad. Then if you want to go back to your current method you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot @OlivierWilkinson that was a great solution! :)

Comment: No problem :) I'll write it down as a proper answer for anybody who is finding the same problem

Comment: Hey @MuneebRehman, sorry if it comes across as pushy but please can you mark my answer as the correct solution? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to add scrolling functionality for text is to use a UITextView. The setup is more or less the same as a label but scrolling is built in.

One thing to note is that users are allowed to edit the text by default, so either in the storyboard or programmatically you should set editable to false for your textView.