# How to calculate estimatedRowHeight for Dynamic Type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have a custom subclass of `UITableViewController`. It has one section containing many rows. Each row corresponds to the same custom table view cell class. Each custom cell has two labels: `myLabel1` & `myLabel2`, both subviews of the cell's `contentView`.

Every `myLabel1` has one line of text, and every `myLabel2` has one or two lines of text, but every cell should have the same height, as if every `myLabel2` has two lines of text.

The labels use Dynamic Type.

```
myLabel1.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
myLabel2.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
```

According to [Working with Self-Sizing Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH25-SW1), I've positioned each label with Auto Layout and "set the table view’s `rowHeight` property to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`" so that the row height changes with Dynamic Type.

1. How do I make every cell have the same height?
2. How should I estimate the table view's row height?

Comment: It depends on the content of cells. With self-sizing u cant control the size. You have to set the same content. Or dont use self-sizing if u want same size.

Comment: Create a constraint that makes the height of label2 equal to label1 .

Comment: Basically every cell of the `UITableView` should have the maximum height that any one cell of your `UITableView` may have at run time?

Comment: remove UITableViewAutomaticDimension for fix sizing. and use tableView delegate method to specify fix or calculated row height .

Comment: I want every cell to have the same height, and that height should change depending on each user's [Dynamic Type](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/typography/) settings. "Dynamic Type  provides additional flexibility by letting readers choose their preferred text size."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180443/adjust-uilabel-height-to-text calculate height for both labels for your maximum possible text. Set it as height for cell in tableview Delegate method .

Comment: Are you sure that you want every single cell to be the same height? That's counter to how self-sizing table cells work, where the height can be different per cell.

Answer (score 2):

`UITableViewAutomaticDimension` will estimate the cell size depending on cells content size. We must calculate the max height that a cell could possibly have, and return this height for all cells instead of using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

**CustomTableViewCell**

```
let kMargin: CGFloat = 8.0

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var singleLineLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var doubleLineLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        updateFonts()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        updateFonts()
    }

    func updateFonts() {
        singleLineLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:.title3)
        doubleLineLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:.body)
    }

    func updateCellForCellWidth(_ width:CGFloat) {
        doubleLineLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width - (2*kMargin)
    }

    func fillCellWith(_ firstString: String, _ secondString: String) {
        singleLineLabel.text = firstString
        doubleLineLabel.text = secondString
    }
}
```

### **On View Controller**

**Setting up a dummy cell and listing to notifications for dynamic type**

```
var heightCalculatorDummyCell: CustomTableViewCell!
    var maxHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        heightCalculatorDummyCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_id") as! CustomTableViewCell
        maxHeight = getMaxHeight()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AutomaticHeightTableViewController.didChangePreferredContentSize), name: .UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange, object:nil)
    }
```

**Getting max height using a dummy cell.**

```
func getMaxHeight() -> CGFloat {
        heightCalculatorDummyCell.updateFonts()
        heightCalculatorDummyCell.fillCellWith("Title","A string that needs more than two lines. A string that needs more than two lines. A string that needs more than two lines. A string that needs more than two lines. A string that needs more than two lines.")
        heightCalculatorDummyCell.updateCellForCellWidth(tableView.frame.size.width)
        let size = heightCalculatorDummyCell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
        return (size.height + 1)
    }
```

**Handling Table view reloads on notification**

```
deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func didChangePreferredContentSize() {
        maxHeight = getMaxHeight()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

**Final step, returning max heights in tableview delegate**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titles.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return maxHeight
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, great answer! Thank you. By the way, a sting that needs two lines can simply be: `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

Make `myLabel2` a `FixedHeightLabel` so that its height is always two lines.

```
class FixedHeightLabel: TopAlignedLabel {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let oldText = text
        text = "\n"
        let height = sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: .max, height: .max)).height
        text = oldText
        return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: height)
    }
}

class TopAlignedLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let textRect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
        super.drawText(in: textRect)
    }
}
```