# UIView/UILabel does not increases in height when using a tall language

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

[image]

Here you can see the black font is larger than its parent view. The height remains 21,5 of the UILabel, no matter what language I use.

I did: -add a UIView, center it X and Y. -Add a UILabel into it, set trailing, leading, bottom and top to 0. -Set the UILabel lines to 0 according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34430402/7715250

But it did not work. How can the UIView/UILabel increases when using a tall language and decreases when using a smaller language?

Comment: What is the vertical compression resistance priority on the UILabel? Try setting it to "Required".

Comment: @MishaKarpenko I setted everything to 1 and to 999, did not work

Comment: Have you tried calling `sizeToFit` on the UILabel?

Comment: You should follow Misha's suggestion for the label and it's parent view as well. The label has fixed distances to it's superview. Can the Superview get bigger?

Comment: @macmoonshine it is not necessary about the parent view, it is about the uilabel. It does not grow, no matter what hugging or compression I set.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. You wrote _set trailing, leading, bottom and top to 0_. This may force the label to fixed height. If you want better help, you should give more detailed information.

Comment: @macmoonshine I mean without using a UIView, so only a UILabel, the height never increases from the UILabel.