# How UILabel height according to text height in Swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel, swift4

I tried a many solutions but not get a right answer.

Here my code:

```
self.AhadeesView = UILabel()
self.AhadeesView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.AhadeesView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
self.AhadeesView.numberOfLines = 0
self.AhadeesView.text = NSLocalizedString("TitleAhadees", comment: "Title Ahadees of the App")
self.AhadeesView.textAlignment = .center
self.AhadeesView.font = UIFont(name:"Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq",size:25)
self.AhadeesView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
//   self.AhadeesView.sizeToFit()

containerView1.addSubview(AhadeesView)
```

Comment: You need to give the label a width before you call `sizeToFit`.

Comment: how give the width??

Comment: Set its `frame` just like any view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust UILabel height to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180443/adjust-uilabel-height-to-text)

Comment: Already tried all of these solution's...

Comment: just do one thing , number of lines = 0 and put label left , right constraint and top and bottom constraint should be 0 ( no height and width constraint ) will fix your issue .

Comment: Where is the issue ?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you have missed your frame to show the label.

```
self.AhadeesView = UILabel(frame: [your frame value])
```

Frame can be created by

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: [height_of_String])
```

[height_of_String] can be calculated by below extension

You can calculate the width and height of the string using the following extension methods

```
extension String {
    //To calculate the height u need to pass the width of the label and the required font size.

    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }

    func width(withConstraintedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.width)
     }
}
```

Comment: used custom font the custom font text height long lable dont adjust the height...

Comment: you can pass the font to this extension

Comment: how this can do that??

Comment: Where is the frame for your label?