# Finding the height of a label before it is written to

Tags: swift, uitableview, label

I'm currently working on a social media app just to try and excel my Swift skills. I'm using the `UIKit` framework to build this app. I've got the feed up and running, and scaling pictures correctly there went fine because I can calculate the height of an image if I know its width and aspect ratio. Now that I've starting working on the comment section, I can't solve the problem this way. I need to find a way to know what height a cell is (the comment section is a `UITableView`). The problem is that to use the result from `label.frame.height`, I must have set its constraints. But when setting constraints, I don't know what the height of the cell is, so it's sort of a circular problem: I don't know the height -> I can't set constraints -> I don't know the height -> ...

What I've tried is calling this function when initializing my custom `UITableViewCell` (which holds the comment and the person who posted it, as well as the number of likes it has):

```
    contentView.addSubview(label)
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14)
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
```

And my `heightForRowAt indexPath` function looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = CommentCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: Cells.commentCell)
    cell.setText(to: comments[indexPath.row].text)
    return cell.fetchCellHeight(with: cell.content)
}
```

where `cell.fetchCellHeight(with:)` is defined as follows:

```
    label.text = text
    return label.frame.height
```

So what I've tried is setting the text and trying to read the label's height, but for some reason this returns 0.0.

So in short, what I'm wondering is how I can find the label's height so that the cells in my `UITableView` get the correct height depending on how much text is in them. I'm doing this all programmatically, so unfortunately any Storyboard solution won't work for this problem unless there is a programmatic equivalent.

Thank you.

Comment: `yourLabel.font.lineHeight` will give you the height of the label if it's a single line. Is your label multiple lines? Also, do you know you can make each cell dynamic based on it's height without using something like `cell.fetchCellHeight`

Comment: These labels would be an unknown number of lines. It's all based on how much text a user comments. If a cell is dynamic, does that mean I can change its height on runtime, and how could I go about doing this?

Comment: Why are you changing the height?

Comment: I just need a way to actually find the height of an arbitrary label. If I do that, I don't need to change its height at runtime. The problem is that I don't know exactly how I can find its height.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adjust UILabel height to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180443/adjust-uilabel-height-to-text)

Comment: So your problem is to estimate the height of label ? Did you see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift