# Rounder by UIBezierPath issue when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibezierpath

I am new in iOS. I am make a chat application. I am using `UITableView` for display the message chat (one cell - one message).
In each cell, I will rounder the message in 2,3 or 4 corner (like Facebook chat)

For rounder I use the `UIBezierPath` inside `layoutSubView` of each `Tableview Cell`

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.messageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
self.messageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

[image]

**The problem is**, when layout first initial, everything work fine, but when I scroll some cell have wrong rounder ( I figure out the problem is sometime when scroll `self.messageView.bounds` return wrong value so `UIBezierPath` draw wrong corner) but I don't know why

How can I prevent it happened? 
Or Can I have another way to rounder View without `UIBezierPath` (I google but I only find one way to rounder the UIView is using `UIBezierPath` :( )?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try this code  [v.layer setCornerRadius:30.0f];

// border
[v.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[v.layer setBorderWidth:1.5f];

// drop shadow
[v.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[v.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[v.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
[v.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];

Comment: @DarjiJigar my requirement is `rounder the message in 2,3 or 4 corner`, your code only make rounder in 4 corners

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview, BUT I guess (and you are saying so) that problem not in drawing but on getting correct bounds, so I would focus on fixit this but not avoiding using Bezier path

Comment: @Injectios Thank you. but in your given link, the accept answer is 5 years ago, and another new answer is using `UIBezierPath` like my code

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by moving my corner-rounding code inside `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath` This will allow Cocoa to size things properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fix it by moving code in layoutSubviews()

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.messageBGView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight,.bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath
            self.messageBGView.layer.mask = self.maskLayer
            self.messageBGView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }
```