# ios TableView different cell height

Tags: ios, tableview

I am working on an app which requires me to show pictures and some text in TableView. These pictures can be of different heights and so I need to vary the cell height accordingly. so I have overridden this method :

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If I have a single static value for cell identifier then the height of the image inside the cell cannot vary dynamically.

So do I need to have different values of Cell Identifier for each cell ? Is there some other way ?

I cannot use some other view than Tableview because I need to show some cells dynamically in between based on user interaction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should reference your data model to get the image size and return the row height.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UIImage *image = dataModel[indexPath.row];
        return image.size.height + 16.0; //16 is for padding
}
```

If you subclass your cell, you can adjust the imageView frame in `-layoutsubviews` (after super):

```
- (void)setupImageView
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.contentImageView = imageView;

    [self.contentView addSubview:imageView];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect bounds = self.contentView.bounds;
    float margin = 8.0;
    CGRect textViewFrame = CGRectZero;
    textViewFrame = CGRectMake(margin, roundf(margin * 2.0), bounds.size.width - (margin * 2.0), roundf(bounds.size.height - (margin * 4.0)));

    self.contentImageView.frame = textViewFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic tableViewCell height use this.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  CGSize labelHeight = [self heigtForCellwithString:yourLabel.text    withFont:yourLabel.font];
    return labelHeight.height; // the return height + your other view height
}

-(CGSize)heigtForCellwithString:(NSString *)stringValue withFont:(UIFont)font{
 CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(300,9999); // Replace 300 with your label width
  NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
  CGRect rect = [stringValue boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                       options:         (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                    attributes:attributes
                                       context:nil];
    return rect.size;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for only an image:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //get reference to a image
    UIImage *image = [arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //get the height of your imageview on the cell
    CGFloat imageViewHeight = image.size.height/2;//RetinaDisplay

    //return the height of the imageview (plus some padding) for your cell height
    return imageViewHeight; //add here also all other constant height's of objects that you have on your cell.
}
```

For a more comprehensive example look at my answer here:

[Resize Custom cell with a UILabel on it based on content text from JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033709/resize-custom-cell-with-a-uilabel-on-it-based-on-content-text-from-json-file/20981305#20981305)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the Cell Height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
  NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

  CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

  CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

  CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

  return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}
```

For more reference see the [Link..](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/)

Comment: the `–sizeWithFont:...` methods have been [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html) since iOS7. :/ you should use here the e.g. `–sizeWithAttributes:` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the height of each cell before the cell display.So,You could write a method to get the height,and then use the method you written in the Model.