# dynamically size multi-line UILabel and accompanying table view cell programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, dynamic-sizing

I'm struggling with how to dynamically size a uilabel inside a uitableviewcell and also to adjust the height of the table cell depending on the text I put into the label. I want to display a string in its entirety within the tableview cell, always at the same font size for all cells. This seems pretty standard, but I notice a lot of discussion/debate/discontent on stackoverflow. I got started with these posts:

[Resize Custom cell with a UILabel on it based on content text from JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033709/resize-custom-cell-with-a-uilabel-on-it-based-on-content-text-from-json-file/20981305#20981305) (@Seya's answer)
[boundingRectWithSize for NSAttributedString returning wrong size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621084/boundingrectwithsize-for-nsattributedstring-returning-wrong-size) (@JOM's answer)

The functions I'm trying to use are copies of what Seya did, barely modified. However, I am seeing that although the function prints out different heights for different cells, all I am seeing is 1 line of text per label even though they should show many lines. Also, strangely the text from one cell seems to display on top of another cell - not sure whether this is related.

My 2 questions: (1) Why do I only see the first line of text? (2) Why is the UILabel/cell not resizing per the different heights I see printed out in the log (or are they resizing but masked by issue #1)?

Here's the three functions I'm using (these along with a xib - could the xib be the problem?):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
JudgeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JudgeCell"];
    if(!cell)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"JudgeCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"JudgeCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JudgeCell"];
    }

    cell.username.text = self.object.answerUser[indexPath.row];
    cell.answer.text = self.object.answerArray[indexPath.row];

    NSString *text = cell.answer.text;
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(50, 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [self frameForText:text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:constraint];

    cell.username.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, size.height); //MAX(size.height, 14.0f));

    return cell;

}

-(CGSize)frameForText:(NSString*)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size  {

    NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;

    NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle
                                  };


    CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                         options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                      attributes:attributes
                                         context:nil];

    NSLog(@"size is %f ", textRect.size.height);
    return textRect.size;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSString *text = self.object.answerArray[indexPath.row];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(50, 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [self frameForText:text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:constraint];
    CGFloat height = size.height; //MAX(size.height, 14.0f);
    NSLog(@"size is %f AT INDEX %d", height, indexPath.row);
    return height + 20;
}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: did you try calling [cell setNeedsDisplay] ? after setting it new size in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @Priyatham51 Yes I tried that as well, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I deleted my associated nib file, and somehow that seemed to do the trick along with the code from this tutorial (which is similar to what I already posted above):

http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

Note that the methods in the tutorial are sometimes flagged as deprecated. If I find an updated tutorial, I will post.