# How is the iPhone SMS compose view implemented?

Tags: iphone, sms

Regarding the SMS compose view as show in the picture below:
[alt text http://www.kennethlund.dk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/iphone_sms.jpg](http://www.kennethlund.dk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/iphone_sms.jpg)

I have two questions:

1) How is the text entry box implemented? There are no standard control from the API and the box is smart enough to resize when you press enter OR when the text is too long. Also the bar resizes with it. How is this done with the least coding?

2) How to code it such that when the keyboard shows up the whole view shifts up? Typically when the keyboard shows, it goes over your current view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching stackoverflow for "uitextView size" produces these results:

[How do I size a UITextView to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content)

[Resizing UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728704/resizing-uitextview)

---

Searching stackoverflow for "keyboard iPhone" produces this result:

[Programmatically align a toolbar on top of the iPhone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574/programatically-align-a-toolbar-on-top-of-the-iphone-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

[TTTextEditor](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Headers/TTTextEditor.h) is an autosize text box, which is part of the [three20](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/) framework