# UITextView wider at runtime than in interface builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitextview

I have a strange issue where I am creating a UITextView in interface builder and constraining it appropriately, yet at runtime it seems to be much wider and runs off the screen.

Screenshots:

Interface builder screenshot: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uyUp.png]

Runtime screenshot: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qscV9.png]

As you can see (hopefully), the UITextView has equal amounts of room either side in the interface builder. Yet at runtime, it spills off the right hand edge.

Any ideas? Thanks very much!

**SOLUTION**

As suggested by 'Mystery' setting the struts and springs fixed it! (I assume this is the struts and springs). See the picture below:

[image: Struts and springs]

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I have notice similar problems when using Autolayout, are you also using it? Also do you have the "size to fit" checkbox enabled? That might cause it too.

Comment: Autolayout is turned off. I am not sure where the 'Size to Fit' checkbox is, could you direct me?

Comment: check it , it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728704/resizing-uitextview--

Comment: My apologies, I must have been dreaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set struts and springs for the UITextView