# How to resize scrollView content and put textViews in that according to their text size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, ios-4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i fix my scrollView dynamically when i have more than one textViews in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065012/how-can-i-fix-my-scrollview-dynamically-when-i-have-more-than-one-textviews-in-it)

I made a scrollView in interface builder and put 3 textViews and 2 button in that. Sometimes textViews have more text and sometimes less. i managed to give them flexible frame size. but if top textView has more text then some of its text comes over 2nd textView. i tried this code. i think it should work but its not working properly.

```
    storyTitle.text = sTitle;
storyTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];

date.text = sDate;  
    date.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];

summary.text = sSummary;
summary.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];

CGRect titleFrame = storyTitle.frame;
titleFrame.size.height = storyTitle.contentSize.height;
storyTitle.frame = titleFrame;

CGRect dateFrame = date.frame;
dateFrame.size.height = label.contentSize.height;
date.frame = dateFrame;

CGRect summaryFrame = summary.frame;
summaryFrame.size.height = summary.contentSize.height;
summary.frame = summaryFrame;

CGRect topTextViewFrame = storyTitle.frame;
CGRect middleTextViewFrame = date.frame;
NSLog(@"size: %d",topTextViewFrame.origin.y);
middleTextViewFrame.origin.y = topTextViewFrame.origin.y + topTextViewFrame.size.height;
CGRect bottomTextViewFrame = summary.frame;
bottomTextViewFrame.origin.y = middleTextViewFrame.origin.y + middleTextViewFrame.size.height;

   // then adjust other controls based on these frames, for example:
CGRect myButtonFrame = detailButton.frame;
myButtonFrame.origin.y = bottomTextViewFrame.origin.y + bottomTextViewFrame.size.height;

CGRect myButtonFrame2 = fbButton.frame;
myButtonFrame2.origin.y = myButtonFrame.origin.y + myButtonFrame.size.height;

// finally adjust the contentSize of the scrollview assuming the button is the bottom element
CGSize csize = scrollView.contentSize;
csize.height = myButtonFrame2.origin.y + myButtonFrame2.size.height;
scrollView.contentSize = csize;
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong with this? and how should i right it so it ll work fine. thanx in advance

Comment: Please edit the original question to add new details instead of opening a new question on the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi if your text is not editable by user the try using UILabel instead of UITextView.If you set numberOfLines property of UILabel = 0 then it can go to more that one line and then u can calculate the required height for the label by the method

```
CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap ];
```

the u can set the frame of label according to height you get form here like

```
 label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x,label.frame.origin.y,label.frame.size.width,size.height);
```

and if you have such multiple labels the uyou can do following

```
CGSize size = [label1.text sizeWithFont:label1.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label1.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap ];
label1.frame =   CGRectMake(label1.frame.origin.x,label1.frame.origin.y,label1.frame.size.width,size.height);

size = [label2.text sizeWithFont:label2.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label2.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap ];
label2.frame =   CGRectMake(label2.frame.origin.x,label1.frame.origin.y+label1.frame.size.height+10,label2.frame.size.width,size.height);

size = [label3.text sizeWithFont:label3.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label3.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap ];
label3.frame =   CGRectMake(label3.frame.origin.x,label2.frame.origin.y+label2.frame.size.height+10,label3.frame.size.width,size.height);
```

and finaly you can adjust the content height of your scroll view according tho last label.