# How do I make NSTextView grow with text?

Tags: objective-c, text, autolayout, nstextview

I am creating a simple word processor where it's possible for the user to add a text box to an `NSView`, similar to the function in Pages. The problem is that when it's added it will stay the same size no matter how much text the user inputs. I want it to grow as the user inputs text, I have tried with this  [GitHub](https://github.com/jerrykrinock/CategoriesObjC/blob/master/NS(Attributed)String%2BGeometrics/NS(Attributed)String%2BGeometrics.m)  project but when I use it the text field only expands when I have deleted all the text, as if the code doesn't react before the `textDidEndEditing` method. After working a bit with `NSTextView` I found that it would be more suitable for the task, but I still can't make it work. I'm running Mavericks and Xcode 5.0.1.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180703/how-do-i-make-a-cocoa-nstextview-grow-as-the-user-types-into-it/40107071#40107071

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example fixed it for me: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html

You have to put it into a NSScrollView. The behavior is not the same as in UITextView (if you have a iOS background).

Answer (score 4):

The following uses an NSTextView subclass that must be created in code. For reasons of its own Xcode won't allow you to instantiate an NSTextView in a nib without an enclosing NSScrollView instance.

This class lets the only defines the text view intrinsic height - the width is left undefined which allows the view to grow with its enclosing view. I used this in an `NSStackView` and it seemed to work well. Trying to bludgeon NSTextField so that it could wrap multiline text, edit and support Auto Layout was too messy.

Note we have support for a focus ring as I wanted my class to act like and Uber text field. Also note that we have no support for a border. In my actual usage I create a compound view that wraps the custom text view. This wrapper view draws a border as required.

```
@interface BPTextViewField : NSTextView

// primitives
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat borderOffsetX;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat borderOffsetY;
@end

@implementation BPTextViewField

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Life cycle

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect textContainer:(nullable NSTextContainer *)container
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect textContainer:container];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit
{
    _borderOffsetX = 1;
    _borderOffsetY = 3;
    self.usesFontPanel = NO;
    self.usesFindPanel = NO;

}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Auto layout

- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    NSTextContainer* textContainer = [self textContainer];
    NSLayoutManager* layoutManager = [self layoutManager];
    [layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer: textContainer];
    NSSize size = [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer: textContainer].size;

    return NSMakeSize(NSViewNoIntrinsicMetric, size.height);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Accessors

- (void)setString:(NSString *)string
{
    [super setString:string];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Text change notifications

- (void)didChangeText
{
    [super didChangeText];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Drawing

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Focus ring

- (void)drawFocusRingMask
{
    if (self.editable) {
        NSRectFill(self.focusRingMaskBounds);
    }
}

- (NSRect)focusRingMaskBounds {
    NSRect r = [self bounds];
    return NSMakeRect(r.origin.x - self.borderOffsetX, r.origin.y - self.borderOffsetY, r.size.width + self.borderOffsetX * 2, r.size.height + self.borderOffsetY * 2);
}


@end
```