# UITextView Auto Height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

How do I make a UITextView expand or shrink to the size of the text inside it and then make the UIScrollview Expand or shrink to fit the UITextView

Comment: It seems like you should be able to do what you're trying to do using -[UIView sizeToFit]. Take a look at the docs for the UIView class and see if that's what you're looking for. Some sample code would help to clarify exactly what you're attempting.

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38418756/3024579

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
CGRect frame;
frame = textiew.frame;
frame.size.height = [textView contentSize].height;
textView.frame = frame;
```

One thing to note is that the correct contentSize is only available **after** the UITextView has been added to the view with addSubview and the text is assigned to it. Prior to that it is equal to frame.size

Comment: textView contentSize doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Does that simplify to `cell.commentLabel.frame.size.height = cell.commentLabel.contentSize.height` in Swift?

Comment: @Darksinge your effort to update code to Swift 2.0 is appreciate, but you need to post it as your own answer.