# How can I resize textview when I input long text?

Tags: ios, textview, autosize

I have a textfield in a tableview 's last cell. The textfield is one line at beginning, when I input some text more than one line, I need the textfield change its height for me can view all text. How can I do this?

edit 1:
I have try text view, it can input multiple line text, but how can I know when it from one line become two line? because I need resize cell height also.

edit 1 's answer 
[UITextView Auto Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237449/uitextview-auto-height)

Comment: as matteodv mentioned, UITextView is probably more what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do something like this with a UITextField because it's intended to be only a field and you can't change its height. Otherwise take a look to UITextView which can be set as you want, its frame etc... You only have to set it as `editable` so you can write text in it.

Comment: There are some app can do this, I just don't know how to do.I think it should have a property to do it, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't saw you says UITextView not UITextField. I will try it, thanks.

Comment: btw UITextField basically is a UITextView wrapped for 1-line mode