# How to adjust UITextView's width to fit its content without wrapping?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview

Resizing UITextView to fit height of its content can be achieved like this:

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

Is there something similar to fit width, without wrapping the content text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content

this might be what u seek?

Comment: @totumus-maximus: That post talks about resizing height. As mentioned already, my query is about the width

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***1)*** You can use **the [NSString UIKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1531844-sizewithattributes?language=objc) to compute the size** taken by the text (and adjust the size of your UITextView accordingly).  You may seen an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18897897/1586231).

For example, if you need to know the CGSize that is taken by your `NSString` if rendered on a single line, use `CGSize sz = [_textView.text sizeWithFont:_textView.font]` then adjust your frame given this size value.

*If you need to know the size taken by your text if rendered on multiple lines, wrapping it if the text reaches a given width, use `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` instead, etc.*

---

***2)*** You may also be interested in **the `sizeThatFits:` and `sizeToFit` methods of UIView**.
The first one returns the CGSize (that fits in the given CGSize passed in parameter) so that your UITextView can display all your text. The second actually do the resizing, adjusting the frame for you.

Comment: +1 for suggesting more than one approaches and explaining clearly. I tried the first approach and it works. Thanks!