# how to set the size of UITextView dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I size a UITextView to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content)

i have a textview called labelTextView i want to set the size of the UITextView dynamically so that according to text in the UITextView the size gets adjusted . i wanted to know how to create it ,any help would be helpful .since i am creating it dynamically i dont need to insert textview in the nib file .

Comment: Common, a simple search with your title found several answers to that question already!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the NSString sizeWithFont: methods to determine the size.

```
CGRect textViewFrame = textView.frame;
CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(textViewFrame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:constrainedSize];
CGRect newTextViewFrame = CGRectMake(textViewFrame.origin.x, textViewFrame.origin.y, textViewFrame.size.width, textSize.height);
textView.frame = newTextViewFrame;
```

Comment: i'll try it out .is there a way where we can change the color of the first word in that textview

Comment: "is there a way where we can change the color of the first word in that textview". No. You can only set the text attributes for the UITextView as a whole.

Comment: textView is the object of UITextView right

Comment: Correct. textView is an instance of UITextView