# resizing text in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How do I resize the text in my UITextView so that it doesn't cut off the text? I have a UITextView set at a specific height and I want the text in that UITextView to fit in that height. In a UITextField you have a adjustSizeToWidth, but not in UITextView

Comment: as far as i know UITextView is a scrollable View, so why would you want to squeeze your text in a specific height when you can just scroll through the text?

Comment: then UITextView isn't what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGRect frame = textView.frame;
frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
textView.frame = frame;
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2487402/253008

EDIT:

You can use

```
-(CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
```

to check the width of the text in the UITextView and then when it reaches your set width you can start lowering the font size

Comment: I wanted the height to be fixed and the text to resize it's font. Not the other way around

Comment: this is tedious as I'll have to try a font one by one

Comment: well you'll have the font you started with, everytime you reach the constrained width just subtract your font size by 1. I'm sure that's pretty much how UITextField does it