# UITextView Content Size too Short

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

I have a UITextView which I would like to dynamically resize dependant on its content.

For some reason the textview is always shorter that its contents! Here's the code:

```
_textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test "];

CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

And here's the result:

[image: UITextView Too Short]

As you can see the UITextView (in white) is too short. If I put more or less contents in there the shortness is the same, i.e.

[image: More Text][image: Less Text]

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't work it out.

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative/19067476#19067476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem using storyboards in iOS7.

My solution was to add this code:

```
    CGRect newTextViewFrame = self.textView.frame;
    newTextViewFrame.size.width = self.textView.contentSize.width + self.textView.contentInset.right + self.textView.contentInset.left;
    newTextViewFrame.size.height = self.textView.contentSize.height + self.textView.contentInset.top + self.textView.contentInset.bottom;
    self.textView.frame = newTextViewFrame;
```

in the `viewDidAppear:` view life cycle method and it was immediately sized to fit it's contents. Unfortunately, this resize happens after the view has already appeared which means that the user sees it happening.

Example:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        CGRect newTextViewFrame = self.textView.frame;
        newTextViewFrame.size.width = self.textView.contentSize.width + self.textView.contentInset.right + self.textView.contentInset.left;
        newTextViewFrame.size.height = self.textView.contentSize.height + self.textView.contentInset.top + self.textView.contentInset.bottom;
        self.textView.frame = newTextViewFrame;
}
```

Comment: I have moved on from this problem as I ended up using a UIWebView instead (for other reasons). I will make this as answered though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add the UITextView to the main view (addSubview) before resizing its frame
(see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content))

Comment: The UITextView is inside a UIScrollView (built in the storyboard) so how would I do this? I'm new to iOS, sorry.

Comment: maybe use [_textView sizeToFit] instead then

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2487402/255463, then I do this:

First, I add a UITextView using the storyboard, then I embed the textView inside a UIScrollView, using the storyboard too, then connect each view with an outlet with the storyboard. Inside the view controller sublass this what I got:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize textView = _textView;
@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test "];
    CGRect frame = self.textView.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.textView.contentSize.height;
    self.textView.frame = frame;

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, self.descriptionView.contentSize.height + 147.0);
}

@end
```

Comment: This is basically what I was doing yeah.

Comment: I believe that, I have just tried again using your code and it does the same thing. Really confused!

Comment: Unfortunately in iOS7 the `contentSize` property of UITextView is not updated immediately when the text is changed. I am developing a workaround.