# iOS7 UITextView contentsize.height alternative

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios7

I'm porting one of apps from iOS 6.1 to iOS 7. I'm using a layout where there's a `UITextView` that has a fix width, but it's height is based on its contentsize. For iOS 6.1 checking the contentsize.height and setting it as the textview's frame height was enough, but it doesn't work on iOS 7.

How can I then create a `UITextView` with a fixed width, but dynamic height based on the text it's showing?

NOTE: I'm creating these views from code, not with Interface Builder.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

With this following code, you can change the height of your UITextView depending of a fixed width (it's working on iOS 7 and previous version) :

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)text andWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [textView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}
```

*With this function, you will take a NSAttributedString and a fixed width to return the height needed.*

If you want to calculate the frame from a text with a specific font you, need to use the following code :

```
- (CGSize)text:(NSString *)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                          options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                          context:nil];
        return frame.size;
    }
    else
    {
        return [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size];
    }
}
```

*You can add that `SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO` on your prefix.pch file in your project as:*

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

You can also replace the previous test `SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)` by :

```
if ([text respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)])‌
```

Comment: i can only give it to you after 24 hours. be patient, it's yours :)

Comment: Maybe you should link to the answers you took them from? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368567/uitableviewcell-with-uitextview-height-in-ios-7

Comment: @Jordan Montel, for another question, if i have fixed width and height , how can i find the best font size for an assigned string? i have the similar issue on iOS7 (on iOS6, i can do that)

Comment: @Jacky : trial and error; increase or decrease the size by 1 until its calculated height is too big. Or make it size 1000 and auto-resize to fit.

Comment: this answer is ALREADY INCORRECT. Try to input a lot of text inside such text field. Suddenly incorrect size? At least `NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading` is extra

Comment: `(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)` helps me a lot.

Answer (score 42):

This worked for me for iOS6 and 7:

```
CGSize textViewSize = [self.myTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.myTextView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
    self.myTextView.height = textViewSize.height;
```

Comment: Hi, Yes its woking for me… I am used "txtviewHeight.frame.size.height" instead of "txtviewHeight.contentSize.height"

Comment: why am i getting property height not found on object of type "UITextView" ?

Comment: @Hexark `textView.bounds.size.height`

Answer (score 21):

In iOS7, `UITextView` uses `NSLayoutManager` to layout text:

```
// If YES, then the layout manager may perform glyph generation and layout for a given portion of the text, without having glyphs or layout for preceding portions.  The default is NO.  Turning this setting on will significantly alter which portions of the text will have glyph generation or layout performed when a given generation-causing method is invoked.  It also gives significant performance benefits, especially for large documents.
@property(NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY) BOOL allowsNonContiguousLayout;
```

disable `allowsNonContiguousLayout` to fix `contentSize` :

```
textView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = NO;
```

Comment: Your answer is not fit the question, but fit my problem. So I vote up :)

Comment: This does not fix content size for me. Scrolling is disabled.

Comment: This piece of code solved my problem, but what does generation-causing method mean on you comment?

Answer (score 15):

Use this little function

```
-(CGSize) getContentSize:(UITextView*) myTextView{
    return [myTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(myTextView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My final solution is based on HotJard's but includes both top and bottom insets of text container instead of using 2*fabs(textView.contentInset.top) :

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeight:(UITextView *)textView
{
    return ceilf([textView.layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textView.textContainer].size.height +
                 textView.textContainerInset.top +
                 textView.textContainerInset.bottom);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are simplier solution, using this method:

```
+(void)adjustTextViewHeightToContent:(UITextView *)textView;
{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0f){
        textView.height = [textView.layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textView.textContainer].size.height+2*fabs(textView.contentInset.top);
    }else{
        textView.height = textView.contentSize.height;
    }
}
```

**UPD**: working just for displaying text (isEditable = NO)

Comment: It seems like your solition doesnt work. When textview goto second line `usedRectForTextContainer` method returns same height.

Comment: Oh, may be, I'v just use it for displaying text

Answer (score 1):

```
   _textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
   _textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
```

Just don't forget the lineFragmentPadding

Answer (score 0):

simple solution - `textView.isScrollEnabled = false`
works perfect when inside another scroll view, or tableView cell with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Answer (score 0):

@Ana's, @Blake Hamilton's solution in **swift**.

```
var contentHeight: CGFloat = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.frame.size).height
```

The good thing for me was that this also returns the correct `contentSize`, when `isScrollEnable` is set to false. Setting to false returned the text view's frame size instead of the content size.