# Resizing UITextView - Height not adjusting

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sizetofit

This should be so easy, but for some reason it's not working for me.   I want to resize my text box and ideally have some padding at the bottom.   For now I'll settle for resizing properly.

**The setup**

A single view on my storyboard

**Interface**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *messageTextBox;
```

**Implementation**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _messageTextBox.text = _message.body;
    [_messageTextBox sizeToFit];  
}
```

I have tried several different solutions including changing the height of the frame and other user suggestions here...

This is using ios7 and xcode 5, but I don't see why there would be an issue with such a basic function.

To add to my confusion, I have logged the frame height and contentsize after sizeToFit.  My results are:

```
2013-10-02 18:40:20.803 narg[21467:a0b] H of the frame: 618.000000
2013-10-02 18:40:20.804 narg[21467:a0b] W of the frame: 469.000000
2013-10-02 18:40:20.804 narg[21467:a0b] Reported H of contentSize property on object 42.000000
```

So the frame clearly knows the correct height, but on the display all the text is cutoff and the box doesn't adjust size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here was the answer to my issue.   At some point I had checked off Autolayout on my view.  This effectively locked the view and didn't allow me to adjust the frame size.

If you are seeing a similar issue that the frame is not resizing try the following:

- Go to interface builder and open the view
- Click on the file inspector
- Deselect auto-layout.

This resolved my issue.

Comment: This is so incredibly helpful. I've wasted hours on this. This one worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative/19067476#19067476) to calculate the good frame of the UITextView depending of your text `_message.body`. You can add a gap to have a bottom padding like this :

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString*)text andWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [calculationView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height + 50; // 5O is your gap for example
}
```

Comment: I think I have tried this, but will try again.   so I would call this just to get the height ?   My height is currently being reported back accurately.  But the frame isn't adjusting...

Comment: something like this should work as this is what we've used on projects

Comment: Use it to calculate your new height and change the frame of your text view