# sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode: iOS7 alternative

Tags: ios7, sizewithfont

Help me please to find an alternative for deprecated method...

```
CGSize size = [title sizeWithFont:buttonFont
                                  minFontSize:10
                               actualFontSize:nil
                                     forWidth:_view.bounds.size.width
                                lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
```

Can (boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:) do this? Something like this...

```
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10], NSFontAttributeName,
                                nil];

    CGSize size = [title boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(_view.bounds.size.width-kBorder*2, _view.bounds.size.height)
                                      options:NSLineBreakByClipping
                                   attributes:attributes
                                      context:nil].size;
```

Am I right?
Looking forward your advices :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to a previous answer I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative/19067476#19067476) using this code :

```
- (CGSize)text:(NSString *)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(7.0))
    {
        NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          font, NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

        CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                          options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                       attributes:attributesDictionary
                                          context:nil];

        return frame.size;
    }
    else
    {
        return [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size];
    }
}
```

Comment: Weak-linking would be a better solution than explicit version check: `if ([text respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)])`

Comment: @akashivskyy Ok thx, I will improve my answer so :)
I'm curious, could you explain me why it is better please ? thanks

Comment: @JordanMontel It's always better to check for the specific API you need than checking the iOS version.