# Replace the deprecation sizeWithFont:minFontSIze:actualFontSize in ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, uifont

In iOS 6 i was using this method:

```
[self.handText sizeWithFont:font 
 minFontSize:10.0f 
 actualFontSize:&maxFontSize 
 forWidth:handWidth/2 
 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
```

xcode 5 says that `'sizeWithFont:minFontSIze:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:' is deprecated:first deprecated in iOS 7`

Now i implemented like this:

```
[self.handText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} 
 minFontSize:10.0f 
 actualFontSize:&maxFontSize 
 forWidth:handWidth/2 
 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
```

here xcode throws another warning saying:
`'Instance method -sizeWithAttributed:minFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:'not found(return type defaults to 'id')`

Can anyone please help me to fix this warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this helper method instead:

```
-(CGSize)frameForText:(NSString*)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode  {

    NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode;

    NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle
                                  };


    CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:attributes
                                         context:nil];

    //Contains both width & height ... Needed: The height
    return textRect.size;
}
```

Use like so, if you need to support both iOS 6 and iOS 7:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_7_0

     titleSize = [self frameForText:self.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelMaxWidth,self.titleLabel.font.lineHeight) lineBreakMode:self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode ];

     subtitleSize = [self frameForText:self.subtitleLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.subtitleLabel.font  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelMaxWidth,self.subtitleLabel.font.lineHeight) lineBreakMode:self.subtitleLabel.lineBreakMode];

#else


     titleSize = [self.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font
                                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelMaxWidth,self.titleLabel.font.lineHeight)
                                            lineBreakMode:self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode];

     subtitleSize =   [self.subtitleLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.subtitleLabel.font
                                              constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelMaxWidth,self.subtitleLabel.font.lineHeight)
                                                  lineBreakMode:self.subtitleLabel.lineBreakMode];
#endif
```

Comment: This isn't an equivalent solution, is it? The method the questioner was originally using would test a variety of sizes if the `actualFontSize` wouldn't fit in the constraints. The solutions in this answer don't seem to do that...?

Answer (score 2):

The method signature is:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs
```

which means you cannot specify any more argument than the first one (array of attributes). So, you are basically using a method (`sizeWithAttributed:minFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`) which is not existing in the iOS SDK.

For a workaround, please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224332/sizewithfontminfontsizeactualfontsizeforwidthlinebreakmode-ios7-alternative).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```