# Cannot change the size of UITextView

Tags: uitableview, interface-builder, ios7, uitextview

I added some tableViewCells to a tableView via Interface Builder, one of them is containing a UITextView.

The tableView is reloaded as an Button gets clicked:

```
- (void)updateViewWithMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    self.someMessage = message;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath method I check for this cell and do the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CellIdentifier = kMyCustomCell;
    MyCustomCell *contentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect textViewFrame = contentCell.contentTextView.frame;
    textViewFrame.size.height = [self heightForContentView];

    NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f\n", textViewFrame.origin.x,
          textViewFrame.origin.y,
          textViewFrame.size.width,
          textViewFrame.size.height);

    contentCell.contentTextView.frame = textViewFrame;
    contentCell.contentTextView.text = self.someMessage;

    return contentCell;
}
```

In heightForContentView() I calculate the height:

```
- (CGFloat)heightForContentView
{
    CGSize boundingRectSize = CGSizeMake(kCustomCellWidth - 20, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGRect textViewRect = [self.someMessage boundingRectWithSize:boundingRectSize
                                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                              attributes:nil
                                                 context:nil];
    return textViewRect.size.height + 20;
}
```

The cell, if I set the row Height to something, resizes properly. But the textView in it does not.
If I click my button twice (the updateViewWithMessage: method gets called again) and then it resizes - that's weird!

By the way: NSLog prints the correct sizes, so they are definitely set, but why does this TextView not resize then?

Can someone help me to solve this problem quickly please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT after comments :**

I think you don't resize your UITextView, add this code before to resize  `contentCell`:

```
contentTextView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(contentTextView.frame), CGRectGetMinY(contentTextView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(contentTextView.frame), textViewFrame.size.height);
```

**Old Answer :**

Maybe you forgot to pass `attributes` to calculate the new size :

```
CGRect textViewRect = [self.someMessage boundingRectWithSize:boundingRectSize
                                             options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:FONT}
                                             context:nil];
```

With `FONT` is your current font.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative/19067476#19067476).

Comment: you cell resize correctly from the new size of your uitextview but your textview don't resize ?

Comment: Yes, I can resize the cell size as height as I want - OK. But I cannot change the size of its containing UITextView, it only changes if I change it in interface builder. But I want to have it more dynamically... The changes I do programatically on the TextView just have NO effect concerning its SIZE.

Comment: try this options  (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)

Comment: nope, does not work as well. The assignment of a new frame to the TextView's property should do the job also. But what's to weird is - as soon as I call updateViewWithMessage: the textView does not get resized. If I call it a second time it does ...

Comment: Hum I think your `[self.tableView reloadData];` doesn't work very well.

Comment: I guess there is no other option?

Comment: I don't think so. Look if your tableView delegate and data source are correctly set, if your .h include <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> and if your tableView outlet is correctly linked

Comment: Solved it via manually programming this crazy UITextView - [cell addSubview:textView];