# Replacing deprecated IOS 7 function for sizeWithFont. How to make it more elegant?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

```
-(CGSize) sizeWithFont2:(UIFont *)font
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)])
    {
        CGSize result = [self sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
        return result;
    }
    return [self sizeWithFont:font];
}
- (CGSize) sizeWithFont2:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)])
    {
        CGRect frame = [self boundingRectWithSize:size
                                          options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                          context:nil];
        return frame.size;
    }
    else
    {
        return [self sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size];
    }
}

- (CGSize) sizeWithFont2:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode) lineBreakMode
{
    return [self sizeWithFont2:font constrainedToSize:size]; //the NSLineBreakMode not used?

}
```

Notice that the code has 3 problems:

1. For `- (CGSize) sizeWithFont2:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode) lineBreakMode`, the parameter lineBreakMode is not used at all. I don't know how to use it in IOS 7. I look around in stackOverflow and the answers there also do not use that parameter.
2. Also I think sizeWithFont: in IOS 6 must call sizeWithFont:constraintedToSize: but with a default size. But what would be the size?
3. Finally I got warning in `[self sizeWithFont:font];` because it's a deprecated function. I want to remove that warning.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

*Point 3 :*

If you use SDK7 you will always have this warning or an error.

*Point 2 :*

You can choose your size like

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, FLT_MAX);
```

You can choose 300 for the width because it's the screen size with a little space for margins.
But, you should use your own values for font and size.

Comment: Why not  CGSizeMake(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX);

Comment: The best way is to get the width of your string using NSAttributedString. I do this to calculate the height of a text view here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative/19067476#19067476