# UITextview contentSize increase automatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

I have a `UITextField` and `UITextView` in a view.

The scenario is like this:

- `textFieldShouldReturn`: method of the `UITextField` makes `UITextView` the `firstResponder`

And now the problem is , every time my textView becomes the first responder the `contentSize` of the `UITextView` increases(ie,every time the cursor moves to a new line)..

Is there any way that the textView's `contentsize` remains the same???

Thanxx in advance..

Comment: for this is happens only in ios 7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative

Comment: I have simply add a textfield and a textview via xib.
And in textFieldShouldReturn I set textview firstResponder..

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
}

Comment: I encountered this problem in my main project..

So I created this sample one just to check..

Comment: Please try this,    
 [myTextView sizeToFit];
 [myTextView layoutIfNeeded];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code.This will solve your problem.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        if([textField isEqual:myTextField])
        {
            [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
            [myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

before set contentSize use sizeToFit

or refer below links it will help you

[iOS7 UITextView contentsize.height alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative)