# How can I make a UITextView big enough to fit its content?

Tags: iphone, ios7, uitextview

I'm looking for 5 hours right now, and no solutions on whole stack overflow is working.
So I hope someone comes with the magic trick.

I set text to the textview like this :

```
[TextMessages setText:[fromOtherView objectForKey:@"message"]];
```

But the content does not fit the textview.
How can I make the `UITextView` big enough to fit the content?

I tried many options like :

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.textContainer.size.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

Its on iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

Try following code: This works in iOS6 and iOS7

```
  CGSize textViewSize = [self.myTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.myTextView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
self.myTextView.height = textViewSize.height;
```

[Check this link for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative)