# Get the exact size of UITextView with sizeWithAttribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, sizetofit

I have a `UISlider` that changes the font size of a `UITextView`. Before changing the font size, I would like to check if the height of my `UITextView` will be inferior to the height of its view container. The problem is that `sizeToFit` and `sizeWithAttribute` are returning different heights for the same font size.

To do that i'm trying to get the height of my `UITextView` with a custom fontSize, but i cannot figure out a way to do so, and don't understand why I don't get the same height when I do:

```
self.photoDescription.text = @"Test"
self.photoDescription.font = [self.photoDescription.font fontWithSize:18];
[self.photoDescription sizeToFit];
NSLog(@"real height %f", self.photoDescription.frame.size.height); 
//getting : 37.5
```

and:

```
NSLog(@"calculated height %f", [self.photoDescription.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[self.photoDescription.font fontWithSize:18]}].height);
//getting: 20.97
```

same thing for:

```
CGRect textRect = [self.photoDescription.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(320, 300)
                                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[self.photoDescription.font fontWithSize:18]}
                                             context:nil];

CGSize size = textRect.size;
NSLog(@"height %f", size.height);
// getting : 20.97
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: It looks like `self.photoDescription` is including the margins around the text, whereas the other options are just giving you the text exclusive of the text view.  (18-point font shouldn't be 37.5 points high).

Comment: How can I calculate the height including the margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer to my question with Jordan Montel Solution:
[iOS7 UITextView contentsize.height alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative/22066512#22066512)

I used his function to get the width :

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)text andWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [textView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}
```