# sizeThatFits sometimes returns a height that is one line more (or less) than my text in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, sizetofit

I try to get the fitting height for a `UITextView` with this code:

```
[textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)].height;
```

It returns the correct value most of the time, but sometimes it returns a value that is one line more or less than the correct height value.

Here is an example when it is correct:

[image: correct height value]

...and here is another when it's wrong (the full text is "California (There Is No End to Love)")

[image: incorrect height value]

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you used auto layout...??

Comment: chek this link may help you......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative

Comment: I already tried all of these, but they did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `UILabel` instead of a `UITextView` solved my problem.

Comment: That's weird because I used an UILabel and I'm having this issue, but no issues if I switched over to UITextView.