# How to get the content Height of dynamically changing Text in textview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a dynamically changing text in `TextView`.I could not be able to get the content Height of `TextView`.

Here is what i tried.

```
let height = self.tvComment.contentSize.height
print("height",height)

let contentSizeComment = self.tvComment.sizeThatFits(self.tvComment.bounds.size)
print("height",contentSizeComment)
```

Why it's not getting the content height of `TextView`?
Hope you understand my problem.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Write it down in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS7 UITextView contentsize.height alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028743/ios7-uitextview-contentsize-height-alternative)

Answer (score 0):

Usethis method to get the height -

```
func heightForString(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()

    return label.frame.size.height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in textdidchange you can use this code,in order to resize when textchange

```
//approxi should be the width of your textview
           let approxi = view.frame.width - 90
//size is the max width and height of textview,1000 can be what ever you want
            let size = CGSize(width: approxi, height: 1000)


   //dont forget to put your font and size
//chey is the text of thetext view
                let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
                let estim = NSString(string: chey).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
```

//estim is height

above it the first method,second method will come in edit
second method is

```
    func pva()  {
//what was the name of my textfield
            let fixedwidth = what.frame.size.width - 40
            let newsize = what.contentSize.height
            self.hrightext.constant = newsize
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }
```

note: both are tested and works in swift4

Answer (score 0):

Your just write code in below delegate of UITextView:-

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView!) {

    let height = self.tvComment.contentSize.height
    print("height",height)

    let contentSizeComment = self.tvComment.sizeThatFits(self.tvComment.bounds.size)
    print("height",contentSizeComment)
}
```

I hope it help you,

Thank you.