# UITextView sizeThatFits gives an answer that's too short in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextview, uiedgeinsets

When you try and do a `sizeThatFits` on a UITextView, if you then set the height of said UITextView to the result, then it's too short!  This answer:

[UITextView Content Size too Short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184583/uitextview-content-size-too-short)

Also seems to fall short as, if you examine the `contentInset` property of the text view, the `contentInset` is all set to zeroes.

Answer (score 19):

The key it use `textContainerInset` rather than `contentInset`.  This will give you the proper buffer on the top and bottom that you're looking for.  So, you'll get something like:

```
textView.text = "Some multiline text";
let size: CGSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, CGFloat.max));
let insets: UIEdgeInsets = textView.textContainerInset; 
textViewHeight.constant = size.height + insets.top + insets.bottom;
```

It's also important to note, that this method must be called after the UITextView has been rendered.  In other words, I originally was resizing this in the `viewDidLoad` method of the controller, when in actuality it had to be in `viewDidAppear`.  This is annoying since the view is already displayed, but I solved it by fading in the few for better aesthetics.

Comment: thanks!! I override `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` in my viewcontroller and call the method it works flawlessly! previously I called the method in `viewDidLoad` and wonder why it wasn't working!