# a little uitextview position

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, uitextview, frame

i am writing this code to load a plist into 2 textview but i want them to adjust their height according to content size which i have done but i want the second uitextview to start from where the first one ends .. please help

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arrresult.count; i++) {


    NSArray *sorteddetail = [self.arrresult sortedArrayUsingFunction:sortint context:NULL];
    DuaObject *duaobj2 = [[DuaObject alloc] initWithFilePath:[sorteddetail objectAtIndex:i]];
    [duaobj2 loadFile];

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollmain.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollmain.frame.size;

    UITextView *subview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((frame.origin.x)+40,(frame.origin.y)+10, 230, 120)];
    UITextView *subview2 = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((frame.origin.x)+40,(frame.origin.y)+160,230, 120)];




    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG_text.png"]];
    subview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [subview setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [subview2 setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];

    subview.layer.cornerRadius = 10 ;
    subview2.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

    NSString *p = [duaobj2 dua_arabic];
    NSString *b = [duaobj2 eng_trans];

    subview.text = p;
    subview2.text = b;

    [self.scrollmain addSubview:subview];
    [self.scrollmain addSubview:subview2];

    subview.editable = NO;
    subview2.editable = NO;

    subview.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    subview2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    subview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    scrollmain.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

    CGRect frame1 = subview.frame;
    CGRect frame2 = subview2.frame;

    frame1.size.height = subview.contentSize.height;
    frame2.size.height = subview2.contentSize.height;

    subview.frame = frame1;
    subview2.frame = frame2;



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two UIWebView for this. After fetching text data from plist ,redirect it on particular web view. and use [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] method to get height in pixel. According to height of pixel you can re-adjust web views frame.

Edit:
Look this one : [How do I size a UITextView to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content)
It will help you.