# UITextView not Resizing for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview

I've published an app for the iPad and I'm working on making it universal. I have a UITextView that I want to resize to fit its contents. The TextView is created via storyboard and referenced through an IBOutlet.  I read the answer to this question [How do I size a UITextView to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content) and am using the code to resize the TextView. This code works perfectly on the iPad, but when I run it on the iPhone, it doesn't resize. I've been working on this problem for many hours, and it has been killing me.

```
//self.speciesDescription is the TextView in Question here:

//set the text
self.speciesDescription.text=[self.modal getdescriptionForSpecies:self.plantDisplayed];

//call the method below
[self resizeTextView:self.speciesDescription];

//resizes the text view to fit the text
-(void)resizeTextView:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGRect contentFrame=textView.frame;
    contentFrame.size.height=textView.contentSize.height;
    textView.frame=contentFrame;
}
```

If I call initWithFrame: on the TextView  before trying to resize it works fine, but it would save me bunches of time and code if I don't have to do this. Doesn't the StoryBoard call initWithFrame: automatically anyways?

**edit:** I ran some tests today and realized that the contentSize property of the textView always has a width of 0 and the height is over 16000. Any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard initialises its views with `initWithCoder:` constructor, not `initWithFrame:`. If you do some custom initialisation, make sure you do it inside `initWithCoder:` method.

Comment: Do you have any idea why It would work on the iPad but not the iPhone though?

Comment: I have not seen your code. I don't know what custom initialisation you do for your view. Maybe you have some device specific code which works correctly on iPad but not on iPhone.