# Autosize UITextView dependent on text

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to adjust my UITextView dependent on the text size,

```
CGRect frame = _text.frame;
frame.size.height = (_text.contentSize.height);
frame.size.width = _text.contentSize.width;
_text.frame = frame;
```

I've tried this code but the problem is that even if there are 5 lines of text it only shows 2 lines (you can scroll for the rest of the text). How do I fix that it just shows 5 lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/50467/1201377) and it's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2487402/1201377)

Comment: why you did not follow the above mention approach!

Answer (score 3):

use this code

```
UIFont font = _text.font;
CGSize textsize = [_text.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(_text.frame.size.width,999) lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail]; 

[_text setFrame:CGRectMake(_text.frame.origin.x,_text.frame.origin.y,_text.frame.size.width, textsize.height)];
```

Comment: UILineBreakModeTailTruncation is deprecated in iOS6 ...

Comment: I'll use NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail instead

Comment: However this doesn't work, it just shows me 1 line of text now and a little piece of the next line... :\

Comment: use word wrapping or char wrapping instead.