# Autoresizing UITextView IOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, sizetofit

I did a lot of research but none helped with my current situation. What I want to do is have an auto resizing `UITextView` that grows as the user types. It starts off with a default height and auto grows as the text increases. I added to `UITextView` to my `UIView` using the `interface builder`. now I just need help with making it auto grow. The answers I found said in IOS7 you use `[myTextView sizeToFit]` which makes it `auto-resize` but looks like this only works for `UITextViews` that are added `programmatically`.

Comment: So are you wanting to show all the text inside a UITextView without scrollbars? What about when you run out of screen real-estate? (space)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content

Answer (score 1):

I made a subclass of UITextView just for that:

https://github.com/MatejBalantic/MBAutoGrowingTextView

It is an auto-layout based light-weight UITextView subclass which automatically grows and shrinks based on the size of user input and can be constrained by maximal and minimal height - all without a single line of code.

Made primarily for use in Interface builder and only works with Auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a delegate for `myTextView` and have it respond to changes in its text.

In your view controller's interface declare that it conforms to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol, e.g.:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

In your view controller's `-viewDidLoad` add this:

```
self.myTextView.delegate = self;
```

Then implement the `-textViewDidChange:` delegate method:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView != self.myTextView)
        return;

    CGFloat const horizontalPadding = 16.0f; // experiment with these padding values
    CGFloat const verticalPadding = 16.0f;   // until the textview resizes nicely

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(textView.bounds.size.width - horizontalPadding, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize textSize;
    if ([textView.text respondsToSelector:@selector(sizeWithAttributes:)]) {
        // iOS7 and above
        NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSValue valueWithCGSize:maxSize], NSViewSizeDocumentAttribute,
                                    textView.font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
        textSize = [textView.text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
    } else {
        // iOS6 and below
        textSize = [textView.text sizeWithFont:textView.font
                             constrainedToSize:maxSize
                                 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    }

    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = textSize.height + verticalPadding;
    textView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try [`HPGrowingTextView`](https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView) before using a custom solution.

In case you do not like it, you would go about it like this:

- Create a `UITextView` with an initial frame and add it to a `UIView`.
- Override the `textViewDidChange:` method and get a `CGSize` of the content using `yourTextView.contentSize` property.
- Use the `height` property of this `CGSize` to set the height of your `UITextView` using `CGRectMake`.

The `contentSize` gives you the exact size of the content in your textView, without using `sizeWithFont:`(deprecated) or `sizeWithAttributes:`.

But here's the catch: If your `textView` is contained inside another `UIView`, you might have to set it's `autoresizingMasks` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`, `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`, `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` as per your need, for the succesful resizing of superviews of the textView.

Try going through the code of `HPGrowingTextView`, and you will understand how this behaviour is implemented.