# Change height constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, height, constraints, autolayout

I want to change the height constraint of a UITextView programmatically so I set the constraint as an outlet in my controller like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *descriptionHeightConstraint;
```

To change it I do the following:

```
self.descriptionHeightConstraint.constant = self.description.contentSize.height;
```

This works if I do it in **viewDidAppear** but the problem with this is that I can see how the height changes after the view displayed which is not very user friendly so I tried doing it in **viewWillAppear** but didn't work there, the height doesn't change. Calling **setNeedsUpdateConstraints** after changing the constraint didn't work either.

Why is working in viewDidAppear and not in viewWillAppear? Any workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question held the answer for me. Thanks @mxch.

Comment: make sure you set the hugging and compression resistance priority to less!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try setting the constant in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead.

Note that using the text view's `contentSize` property to set the text view's height does not work in iOS 7. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18837714/1239263

Comment: Just tried that, in the iOS6 simulator works fine, the view display and the height is correct but in iOS7 I can see how the height changes after the view displayed. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked with that, now I check if it is iOS7 and do as it is explained in the answer you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your post. This fixed my same issue for iOS8, however, it crashes the app for iOS7. Any idea why? I'm still investigating.

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews() WORKED after lots of searching!! thank you!!