# Setting constrains in code

Tags: ios, constraints

How can I set this constrains in code ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this...

[Creating layout constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826878/creating-layout-constraints-programmatically)

or this..

[Change height constraint programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930000/change-height-constraint-programmatically)