# UITextView does not update its height after trying to change its height programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextview

I just want to modify the height of a `UITextView`.
The log resulting from the code below, says that in fact, the
height changed from 30 to 400:

```
println(txtresponses.frame.height)       // returns 30    
var newFrame:CGRect=txtresponses.frame
newFrame.size.height=400
txtresponses.frame=newFrame
println(txtresponses.frame.height)   // returns 400
```

However, visually, the `UITextView` "txtresponses" remains with the same size.
I am new to `Swift` and `Xcode`, so all my tricks are already exhausted here, and I dont know if it is an iOS version issue, or some typical `Xcode` whim.
What is the correct way to modify a `UITextView` ´s height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to call `txtresponses.frame=newFrame` in the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      txtresponses.frame=newFrame
    }
```

All UI updates must be done from the main thread.

Comment: Great ! This is a common beginner mistake. Keep this in mind: UI = main thread. Always.

Answer (score 0):

Its not work because I think you are using Autolayout with constraint. Please check below url which may help you - [Change height constraint programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930000/change-height-constraint-programmatically)

Answer (score -1):

Might be issue Autolayout. u just remove the autolayout and check it will work. Check below code i hope it will help you.

Example :

```
  import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
        @IBOutlet var butt: UIButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton)    {

            var newFrame:CGRect=textView.frame
            newFrame.size.height=400
            textView.frame=newFrame
        }


    }
```

Screen 1:
[image]

Screen 2: 
[image]