# Make UITextView multiline

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm building an iOS application and I have a UITextView which I fill with a text. The text view is not big enough to store all the text so it just put "..." so that I can't see the rest of the text I've put in the view. Is there a way for me to make the UITextView to be multiline so that it can store all the text I've put in it?

Code :

```
instructionsTextField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
instructionsTextField.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, self.view.bounds.size.width-10, 90);
instructionsTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
instructionsTextField.alpha = 0.5;
instructionsTextField.delegate = self;
instructionsTextField.text = string;
[mapView_ addSubview:instructionsTextField];
```

**Solved**
My problem was that I've said that instructionsTextField is a UITextView but then I've allocated it as UITextField. Now it works fine.

Comment: You can paste all your text in text view from your xib.It will automatically become scrollable,.

Comment: The `UITextView` class implements the behavior for a `scrollable, multiline` text region.

Comment: UITextView can contain multiline text by default. Are you sure you use UITextView, instead of UITextField?

Comment: @Impossible I want to make it programatically.

Comment: @Greg Yes. I googled some other questions from SO and found that I have to have UITextView instead of UITextView and I changed my view but I still cannot make it multilined.

Comment: @WWJD programatically also you no need to specify number of lines it will take it automatically. Please check frame of textview

Comment: @WWJD Can you please paste your code?

Comment: Can you show the code, please?

Comment: Look at this Question,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content?rq=1

Comment: @WWJD, you using textfield, not textview.

Comment: @Ramdy Oh, I see now. I've forgot to change UITextField to UITextView in the allocation.

Comment: Its better to use textview instead of textfield, if your usage is just to enter some sentense. Anyhow look at my answer. @WWJD

Comment: Please change caption of this question @WWJD

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are using **UITextField** here, it cannot be made multilined(unless you add a view in it).
please use **UITextView** instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
Make UITextView multiline
```

The `UITextView` class implements the behavior for a `scrollable, multiline` text region.
You only need to create the `frame` like

```
UITextView *text = [[UITextView alloc]init];
text.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 60, 60);
text.text = @"Your Text. Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your
Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your 
Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your Text.Your";               
[self.view addSubview:text];
```

this will be automatic scrollable  because

`UITextView` Inherits from `UIScrollView : UIView : UIResponder : NSObject`

So there is no need to manage `UIScroll` only define your `frame` size as in the code and add your text will be scroll automatically as per your `text`.

**Note** May be Mistake your side if you talking about `UITextField` the cannot made multi lined.

Answer (score 3):

Write it

```
     instructionsTextField=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
     instructionsTextField.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, self.view.bounds.size.width-10, 90);
     instructionsTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     instructionsTextField.alpha = 0.5;
     instructionsTextField.delegate = self;
     instructionsTextField.text = string;

     instructionsTextField.scrollEnable=YES;
     instructionsTextField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     instructionsTextField.editable=NO;

    [mapView_ addSubview:instructionsTextField];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you created textview by code,. If yes, increase the textview framesize and contect size. 
Look at this Question,

[How do I size a UITextView to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to implement a multiline uitextview :

```
label = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(99, 0, widthLabel-14, 112)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
label.delegate = self;
NSString *text = @"Here is my text, replace it with a longer one to see how the uitextview behaves";
NSInteger _stringTotalLength=[text length];
NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                          value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0]
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringTotalLength)];
label.attributedText = attString;
```

The uitextview will become scrollable when a longer text is inserted.