# Adding/removing views dynamically with autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a pretty complex view and am trying to update it to work with autolayout (while I learn autolayout at the same time). Here is a screenshot of my view:

[image: IB screenshot]

The only thing that you can't see is that all of these views are wrapped in a containerView and that container is sitting in a vertical scrolling UIScrollView.So if there was a really long description or something you would be able to scroll vertically.

My first problem is that I can't figure out how to get the descriptionView (red background) to adjust it's height dynamically (I have scrolling disabled in IB and again in code). I think it might be related to the bottom constraint to the imageScrollView.

The second problem is that the imageScrollView needs to be removed half the time. It holds multiple pictures of an item. But sometimes the item doesn't have pictures so I just want to remove the scrollView in that instance. I call removeSubview in code and want things to just readjust without having to set up a bunch of new constraints. So I added a top space constraint from the Question/Comments label to the bottom of the description and changed its priority to 900 instead of 1000. This seemed to solve my first problem and when I remove the imageScrollView the description view resized to the size of the content. However my scrollView that holds all of the content didn't scroll anymore, I am assuming that the containerView's height got screwed up or something.

Edit: the more I think about this the more I think that figuring out how to add a contraint for the size the descriptionView's height to match the content will solve the other problem as well. Here is another screenshot with the current constraints.

[image: Constraints Screenshot]

### SOLUTION

I don't feel it is fair to post my own solution as the accepted answer. So I am posting my solution within the question, and giving the accepted answer to Nikita for trolling all the questions related to textViews being sized to their content.

My first problem is solved by using this: [Github - Resizable Text View](https://github.com/Nikita2k/resizableTextView)

The second issue was just a matter of setting up the constraints correctly. The red textView had a constraint to the bottom of the superview(contentContainer) (the superview which sets the height of the the main scrollView.) So when I removed textView then the contentContainer view didn't have a height constraint. So I ended up removing the constraint from the textView to the superview (which is the contentContainer) and made a constraint from the bottom of the commentTextView to the contentContainer. This solved the problem. Whenever I remove the red textView everything shrinks up the way I desire.

Comment: What class is `descriptionView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, that my solution is the best one, but I've done it in the following manner (I think that will help you with red text view): [How do I size a UITextView to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content/24950357#24950357)

Unfortunately, I didn't understand you about second problem. Please, provide more details. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, I found your Github and stole your solution before you even posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the image view.  Just give it a zero-height constraint.  That way you don't have to mess with any of your other constraints.