# Update height UITextView for text size

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I'm trying to update a `TextView` dependent on the text that is inside it. I need to increase the height to the bottom direction when a user enters more text. than can fit on one line.

I'm currently using the following code:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = [self textViewHeightForAttributedText:
                       [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text]
                       andWidth:self.frame.size.width];

    [self setNeedsLayout];

}

- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText: (NSAttributedString*)text andWidth: 
(CGFloat)width {
    UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [calculationView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}
```

However, this isn't updating the height of the `UITextView`. I have set the delegate of the `UITextView`. This code is written in a subclass in a subclass of `UITextView`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not actually changing the height of the textView, you're just creating a new frame with the same dimensions of the textView, resizing the new frame, then doing nothing with it.

Try adding:

```
textView.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: I see, I added the line but unfortunately this doesn't help. Even though I think you're right so I'll leave that line in :)

Comment: Can you make sure textViewDidChange is being called? Pop an NSLog statement in there and make sure you see the console message each time a key is pressed.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure, double checked that just yet.

Comment: What sort of class is this object i.e. what is 'self'. Is it inheriting from a UITextView, and is the UITextView you are trying to update an instance of this class? Or is 'self' a view controller? In which case, what is self.frame?

Comment: self is the UITextView. I'll mention that this is written in a subclass of UITextView

Comment: Are you using autolayout? If so, you could just call [self sizeToFit] inside textViewDidChange.

If not, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2487402/3642906

Comment: Yes, I'm using autolayout. Somehow, none of these solutions seem to work. As for the answer you're linking to, that doesn't work for a subclass of `UITextField` (hence the constraint). Is there maybe something obvious that I should take into account with this subclass that I'm not?

Comment: What's the reason for using a subclass? Are you overriding any methods which might be relevant? Or maybe there's some funny stuff going on with the textview being a delegate of itself? Maybe try setting the delegate to your viewcontroller and moving the relevant functions there.

Comment: I need to use a UITextView with that kind of behaviour more then once in my app, so therefore the subclass. I'll try and see if moving the delegate methods have anything useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Coco-control named HPGrowingTextView for i OS.Similar to the one Apple uses in the SMS.

Go through this link.https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hpgrowingtextview

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGSize size =   [self sizeOfText:textView.text widthOfTextView:TextviewWidth withFont:myFont];
    NSLog(@"Height : %f", size.height);
    txtView_Details.frame = CGRectMake(txtView_Details.frame.origin.x, txtView_Details.frame.origin.y, txtView_Details.frame.size.width, size.height);
}

-(CGSize)sizeOfText:(NSString *)textToMesure widthOfTextView:(CGFloat)width withFont:(UIFont*)font
{
    CGSize ts = [textToMesure sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width-20.0, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return ts;
}
```