# Increase the height of UITextView according to its content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a remarks section in in my project and I want to add these remarks in a `UITextView`. I want it so that when I add long text into the text view the entire text view grows vertically to accommodate the text.

I don't want the `UITextView` to scroll. Instead I want it to increase its height depending on its contents.

When we have short text I want it like this:

[image: short text]

When I add a long text to the text view it should increase its height like this:

[image: long text]

How do I implement it so the height automatically increases like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the size of the text by using NSAttributedString.

```
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textView.text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textView.font}];
float width = [string size].width;
float height = [string size].height;
// Then set the UITextView size using height and width
```

You could implement this in the delegate method: `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` and constantly adjust the size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like that:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
  {
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
    textview.scrollEnabled = NO;
  }
```

Comment: That is the exact copy of [How do I size a UITextView to its content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content). Just reference the question rather than copying.